# Find multiplicative inverse existense.

Tags: finite-fields, inverse

I cannot find whether multiplicative inverse of $x^3+x^2+x+1 \pmod{x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1}$ over $\mathrm{GF}(3)$ exists. This problem must be solved with Extended Euclidean algorithm.

I tried to divide $x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1$ by $x^3+x^2+x+1$.

I think I divided it wrong. I got $x^2-2x-2$.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It sounds like the task really is to find whether the coset $x^3+x^2+x+1+I$ in the ring $GF(3)[x]/I$ has a  multiplicative inverse or not. Here  $I$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1$.

Comment: $$x^3+x^2+x+1 = x^2(x+1)+(x+1) = (x^2+1)(x+1)$$ while $$x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1 = x^4(x+1)+x^2(x+1)+x(x+1)+(x+1) = (x^4+x^2+x+1)(x+1)$$ and so the gcd is not a constant. Of course, this is not using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as seems to be required, but I hope the results obtained by that method will be consistent with this observation.

Comment: If it's too much work / too error prone, then don't bother doing a complete division: you can make progress even if all you compute is the leading term of the quotient, which can be obtained by inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is not clearly stated, but what is clear is that you are having some difficulty with polynomial division, or (more likely) just *think* that you are.  What probably happened is something that happens to everybody, a slip with signs.

We will do ordinary polynomial division.  To start the division process, imitate school division. The polynomial $x^3+x^2+x+1$ "goes into" $x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1$ how many tines? Clearly $x^2$ times. So multiply $x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x^2$, subtract from 
 $x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1$.  The raw remainder we get is $-2x^2-x+1$. Since we are working over the $3$ element field, this can be rewritten in various ways. It is sensible to replace the $-2$ by $1$, obtaining remainder $x^2-x+1$, or $x^2+2x+1$.

If negatives give you trouble, you could start by replacing $x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1$ by $x^5+x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+1$.

Anyway, we have quotient $x^2$, remainder $x^2-x+1$. Continue the Euclidean algorithm process by dividing $x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x^2-x+1$. You should get quotient $x+2$ (or $x-1$), remainder some version of $2x-1$. Continue.

Comment: Yet the OP's title is "existence of multiplicative inverse"...the only pol's that are invertible over a field are the constant ones.

Comment: @DonAntonio I thought the possibility of an inverse of a polynomial in the ring $\mathbb F_3[x]/(x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1)$ was under investigation, not an inverse over a field.

Comment: @Dilip But then it is *not* the mult. inverse of "a polynomial" in that field, but of an element of it which, I agree, can be represented by a polynomial-like element...